# "Operation not Permitted" when running Vault in a container

Tags: alpine-linux, hashicorp-vault

We are running the vault-cli in an Alpine Docker image within our GitLab CI.
After an upgrade we are getting this when Vault is called:

```
/bin/bash: line 117: /usr/sbin/vault: Operation not permitted
```

Felix

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/10048#issuecomment-700779263), add this to your Dockerfile:

```
apk add --no-cache vault libcap
setcap cap_ipc_lock= /usr/sbin/vault
```

Note though that this is only secure when not using vault as server here.