# Possible to add kaniko to alpine image or add jq to kaniko image

Tags: gitlab, dockerfile, kaniko

This is how I'm using kaniko to build docker images in my gitlab CI, which is working great.

But I need to read a json file to get some values. Therefore I need to get access to `jq`.

**.gilab-ci.yml**

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"auth\":\"$(echo -n ${CI_REGISTRY_USER}:${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} | base64)\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - |
      /kaniko/executor \
        --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR \
        --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/app/Dockerfile \
        --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/app:latest \
      done
    - jq # <- Is not working, as jq is not installed
```

Is it possible to add jq to the image to avoid installing it always and repeatedly on this stage?

On all other stages I'm using my own alpine image to which I added everything I need in my CI pipeline. So another option would be to add kaniko to this image - if possible. That would result in one image which has all utilities needed.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:3.14.2

RUN apk --update add \
  bash \
  curl \
  git \
  jq \
  npm
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl
# Add kaniko to this image??
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Official Kaniko Docker image is built from `scratch` using standalone Go binaries (see [Dockerfile from Kaniko's GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/deploy/Dockerfile)). You can re-use the same binaries from official image and copy them in your image such as:

```
# Use this FROM instruction as shortcut to use --copy=from kaniko below
# It's also possible to use directly COPY --from=gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor AS kaniko

FROM alpine:3.14.2

RUN apk --update add \
  bash \
  curl \
  git \
  jq \
  npm
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl

#
# Add kaniko to this image by re-using binaries and steps from official image
#
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/executor /kaniko/executor
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-ecr-login /kaniko/docker-credential-ecr-login
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env
COPY --from=kaniko /etc/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/.docker /kaniko/.docker

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin:/kaniko
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
ENV DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_GCR_CONFIG /kaniko/.config/gcloud/docker_credential_gcr_config.json
```

---

EDIT: for the debug image, Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug AS kaniko

FROM alpine:3.14.2

RUN apk --update add \
  bash \
  curl \
  git \
  jq \
  npm
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.21.4/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl

#
# Add kaniko to this image by re-using binaries and steps from official image
#
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/ /kaniko/
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/warmer /kaniko/warmer
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr /kaniko/docker-credential-gcr
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-ecr-login /kaniko/docker-credential-ecr-login
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr /kaniko/docker-credential-acr
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/.docker /kaniko/.docker
COPY --from=busybox:1.32.0 /bin /busybox

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin:/kaniko:/busybox
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
ENV DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_GCR_CONFIG /kaniko/.config/gcloud/docker_credential_gcr_config.json
```

Note that you need to use `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug` (for latest version) or `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.6.0-debug` as source (or another tag)

---

Tested building a small image, seems to work fine:

```
# Built above example with docker build . -t kaniko-alpine
# And ran container with docker run -it kaniko-alpine sh
echo "FROM alpine" > Dockerfile
echo "RUN echo hello" >> Dockerfile
echo "COPY Dockerfile Dockerfile" >> Dockerfile

executor version
executor -c . --no-push

# Output like:
#
# Kaniko version :  v1.6.0
#
# INFO[0000] Retrieving image manifest alpine             
# INFO[0000] Retrieving image alpine from registry index.docker.io 
# INFO[0000] GET KEYCHAIN                                 
# [...] 
# INFO[0001] RUN echo hello                               
# INFO[0001] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...        
# INFO[0001] cmd: /bin/sh                                 
# INFO[0001] args: [-c echo hello]                        
# INFO[0001] Running: [/bin/sh -c echo hello]             
# [...]
```

Note that using Kaniko binaries outside of their official image is [not recommended](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko), even though it may still work fine:

> kaniko is meant to be run as an image: `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor`. We do not recommend running the kaniko executor binary in another image, as it might not work.

Comment: I need to use the debug version as only in this version there is busybox included which is needed in my CI. https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/deploy/Dockerfile_debug So there is only the difference in the added busybox? Could you please adapt your answer using this Dockerfile?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question. Looks like the diffs are: adding busybox and a few diff in how some binaries are built

Comment: It's important to note that this Dockerfile can't be built with kaniko, it must be built with docker/buildkit or maybe `buildah bud`. Even the kaniko project uses docker to build its own executor images.

Comment: Is it possible to install other binaries in the kaniko image? It seems kaniko unpacks everything in / and as a result all other binaries added are removed after running kaniko executor command

Answer (score 4):

I had the same need, as the image was to be used as the basis for a job in a Gitlab CI.
I had to make some small modifications to make it work. If it helps, here is my version (no need for kubectl in my case, I just needed to be run kaniko and vault in the same container) :

- Added libcap to address this issue : ["Operation not Permitted" when running Vault in a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284884/operation-not-permitted-when-running-vault-in-a-container). **Only secure when not using vault as a server.**
- Added missing env variable SSL_CERT_DIR
- Removed Busybox (not needed anymore as we're running an Alpine container)
- Optional kaniko executor entrypoint

```
FROM gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug AS kaniko
FROM alpine:3.14.2

RUN apk --update add jq vault libcap
RUN setcap cap_ipc_lock= /usr/sbin/vault

COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/ /kaniko/

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/bin:/kaniko
ENV DOCKER_CONFIG /kaniko/.docker/
ENV DOCKER_CREDENTIAL_GCR_CONFIG /kaniko/.config/gcloud/docker_credential_gcr_config.json
ENV SSL_CERT_DIR /kaniko/ssl/certs

#ENTRYPOINT ["/kaniko/executor"]
```

Comment: This command makes troubles as it neglects other certificates:

ENV SSL_CERT_DIR /kaniko/ssl/certs

It's better to  use these:

RUN cp /kaniko/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca-certificates-kaniko.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

Answer (score 3):

With kaniko 1.9.2 and alpine 3.17.3, I had errors in libssl libcrypto symlik :

```
Couldn't eval /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3 with link /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3
Couldn't eval /usr/lib/libssl.so.3 with link /usr/lib/libssl.so.3
```

To fix it :

```
# Install and fix libssl / libcrypto
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache  \
      ca-certificates \
      curl \
      unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -f /usr/lib/libssl.so.3 && \
    rm -f /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3 && \
    ln /lib/libssl.so.3 /usr/lib/libssl.so.3  && \
    ln /lib/libcrypto.so.3 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment on [@Pierre B.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5465973/pierre-b) answer I am writing my comment as a separate answer. In general [his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69251129/15045604) worked for me, but I had to change the following line

```
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr /kaniko/docker-credential-acr
```

to

```
COPY --from=kaniko /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env /kaniko/docker-credential-acr-env
```

I hope that this helps further.

Comment: Thank you so much @mokanina for that note! I faced the same problem and using your line fixed the issue.
I edited the accepted answer to make it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I use the kaniko image too to build Docker images in Gitlab CI.

The simple way to add `jq` i use is like this :

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/bin && wget -q -O /usr/local/bin/jq https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases/download/jq-1.7/jq-linux-amd64
```