# Gitlab CI/CD - Artifacts retrieved in one job but not the other

Tags: linux, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm noticing that I can access and export values from a file in one of my Gitlab CI jobs but not the other(s), even though it's clearly in the directory.

This is a part of my gitlab-ci.yml:

```
.terraform:
  extends: .base
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest
  before_script:
    - pwd
    - ls
    - if [ -f build.env ] ; then set -o allexport && source build.env && set +o allexport ; fi
    - env | sort
```

...

```
.docker-build:
  extends: .base
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - pwd
    - ls
    - if [ -f build.env ] ; then set -o allexport && source build.env && set +o allexport ; fi
```

My .terraform extended jobs can make use of build.env just fine:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:23
$ pwd
/builds/project/prototypes-cicd
$ ls
Dockerfile
LICENCE.txt
Procfile
README.md
VERSION.txt
app
build.env
docs
lib
listen-on-port.js
package-lock.json
package.json
public
scripts
server.js
start.js
terraform
usage-data-config.json
$ if [ -f build.env ] ; then set -o allexport && source build.env && set +o allexport ; fi
$ env | sort
```

But the .docker-build extended jobs cannot:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ pwd
/builds/project/prototypes-cicd
$ ls
Dockerfile
LICENCE.txt
Procfile
README.md
VERSION.txt
app
build.env
docs
ecr_token.env
lib
listen-on-port.js
package-lock.json
package.json
public
scripts
server.js
start.js
terraform
usage-data-config.json
$ if [ -f build.env ] ; then set -o allexport && source build.env && set +o allexport ; fi
/scripts-89568-12282862/step_script: source: line 181: build.env: not found
```

I have tried with a different .env file entirely and got the same result

I don't really understand this one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug` image is using [busybox](https://www.busybox.net/) which has a super limited shell binary.

```
$ docker run --entrypoint="" -it --rm gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug sh
/workspace # which sh
/busybox/sh
/workspace # cat > a.sh << EOF
> echo 123
> EOF
/workspace # chmod +x a.sh
/workspace # ./a.sh
123
/workspace # if [ -f a.sh ]; then source a.sh; fi
sh: source: a.sh: not found
/workspace # source a.sh
sh: source: a.sh: not found
```

You have two options:

1. Not use shell scripts in Kaniko.
2. [Build your own Kaniko image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69182455/possible-to-add-kaniko-to-alpine-image-or-add-jq-to-kaniko-image) with normal shell support.